# How to tell sbteclipse to ignore src/main/java?

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

How can I get the sbt-eclipse plugin to **ignore** adding/creating the **src/main/java** and src/test/java to the eclipse .classpath?

I dont have these folders and when I run >eclipse the eclipse-sbt-plugin creates those folders and adds to eclipse .classpath.

build.sbt file

```
name := "myproject"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

resolvers += "google-api-services" at "http://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/mavenrepo"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % "test"

libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.10-M1" % "test"

EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.Unmanaged, EclipseCreateSrc.Source, EclipseCreateSrc.Resource)
```

projects/plugins.sbt file

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

Thanks.

Comment: No I did not. At the time I tried to poke around a bit in the sbt eclipse plugin code, didn't find any options to do this.

Comment: @saad Are you still looking for this answer or is mine  good enough?

Comment: @Rinmalavi yes indeed your answer looks good, I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior of sbt to have javaSources and scalaSources in classpath.
Them being in eclipse is just a consequence.

It can be changed with (for only java project):

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := (javaSource in Compile).value :: Nil
```

or (for only scala project)

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := (scalaSource in Compile).value :: Nil
```

or just remove them all

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := Nil
```

You can do it like this:

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Test <<= (sourceDirectory){ src => src / "somerandompathfortestsources" :: Nil}
```

To see what they are (in sbt console):

```
show unmanagedSourceDirectories
show sources
...
```

To see what makes them:

```
inspect unmanagedSourceDirectories
...
```

More about:
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/docs/Detailed-Topics/Java-Sources.html